# How create component in Angular Testbed when component template has an a tag with routerLink attribute?

Tags: angular

I am compiling the component this way:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModules, RouterTestingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  declarations: [SigninComponent, LoaderComponent],
  providers: [
    MatSnackBar, {
      provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub
    }, {
      provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
        snapshot: { params: Observable.of({ email: 'test@email.in' }) }
      }
    }, {
      provide: NgZone, useClass: MockNgZone
    },
    LoaderService,
    FormBuilder,
    StoreOperationService
  ]
})
await TestBed.compileComponents()
```

The template has the following a tag:

```
     <a [routerLink]="[forgotPasswordUrl]">Forgot password?</a>
```

I get the following error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at new RouterLinkWithHref (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/router/@angular/router.es5.js:5028:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:41957:42)
```

This is the RouterStub:

```
    class RouterStub {
        navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; }
    }
```

How do I get rid of the error?

Comment: You can check call stack of this error (router.es5.js), but that's possibly because you you've stubbed ActivatedRoute incorrectly, and it lacks some properties. Consider replacing routerLink directive with a stub, so the test won't use real router at all.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I should configure my test bed? I have edited my question with the stub

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @estus's comment, I was pointed to the right direction. This [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/testing/ts/src/testing/router-stubs.ts) provides stubs for various routing directives.

I created a stub file:

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core'
@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick()'
 }
})
export class RouterLinkStubDirective {
  @Input('routerLink') linkParams: any
  navigatedTo: any = null

  onClick() {
    this.navigatedTo = this.linkParams
  }
}
```

The new TestBed configuration looks like:

```
class RouterStub {
    navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; }
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModules, BrowserAnimationsModule],
  declarations: [SigninComponent, LoaderComponent, RouterLinkStubDirective],
  providers: [
    MatSnackBar, {
      provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub
    }, {
      provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
        snapshot: { params: Observable.of({ email: 'test@email.in' }) }
      }
    }, {
      provide: NgZone, useClass: MockNgZone
    },
    LoaderService,
    FormBuilder,
    StoreOperationService
  ]
})
await TestBed.compileComponents()
```

I have removed the `RouterTestingModule` import and added the `RouterLinkStubDirective` to the declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the router testing module.

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
```

And add it to the module of your test bed:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {path: '/forgot', component: ForgotPasswordCmp}
        ])
      ]
    });
  });
```